# How to remove Sprite from scene using Andengine in android

Tags: android, physics, andengine

I have used the pScene.detachChild(face); to remove Sprite from scene. It hide face object but not delete from the scene. How can i remove from scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing:

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/SpriteRemoveExample.java

Example code:

scene.detachChild(childSpriteVariable);

Adding:

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/SpriteExample.java

Example code:

final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion);
scene.attachChild(face);
I'm basically getting this information by browsing this site. It seems to be the only official docs this engine has:

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have used as defined in SpriteRemoveExample but it works like invisible of objects not removing object

Answer (score 1):

Reference to the Sprite is still stored inside the variable `face`. Calling `face = null;` should allow the garbage collector to free the memory occupied by the Sprite unless you store a reference to it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is posted a long time ago, but maybe i can help someone new who also have similar problem.

To delete Sprite, just unload texture which is used for generating Sprite. 
Somehow connect texture with sprite, and when you need to remove sprite, just unload texture (TextureRegion).